# Is the Laplace transform of $f(-t)$ given by $F(-s)$?

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

Suppose $f(t)$ is an *even* function, then we have $f(t) = f(-t)$, thus

$$F(s) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}\,dt =  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-t)e^{-st}\,dt $$

From here I'm not so sure how to proceed. I need to somehow show that $F(s)=F(-s)$ when $f(t)$ is an *even* function. To do this, it looks I need to show that the Laplace transform of $f(-t)$ is given by $F(-s)$. Should I substitute $u=-t$ ? Then I get

$$F(s) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}\,dt =  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-t)e^{-st} \,dt=  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)e^{su}\,dt$$

But this is not in the standard laplace integral form. How to conclude that this equals $F(-s)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$F(-s)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{ts}\,\mathrm dt,$$if you do $t=-u$ and $\mathrm dt=-\mathrm du$, you get$$F(-s)=-\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}f(-u)e^{-us}\,\mathrm du=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(u)e^{-us}\,\mathrm du=F(s).$$

Comment: Oh yes, we can directly replace s by -s in the integral to get F(-s)! Thank you for making it clear :) I feel so dumb I didn't see this.

Comment: @rsadhvika If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes I was stuck before going through your answer. It started to make sense only after your answer. Thank you so much :)

Comment: This isn't quite accurate: $f(-u)$ became $f(u)$ in the next to last equality. A cleaner way would be to say that if $\mathcal L[f] = F$, then $\mathcal L[f(-t)] = F(-s)$.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** conclude that- it isn't true.  For example, take $f(t)= e^t$.  Its Laplace transform is $\frac{1}{s- 1}$ but the Laplace transform of $f(-t)= e^{-t}$ is $\frac{1}{s+ 1}$, **NOT** $\frac{1}{(-s)- 1}$.

Comment: Oh, Is this something to do with the limits. I'm considering $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and you seem to be taking $0$ to $\infty$ ?

Comment: Then if $f(t) = e^tu(t)$ we have $f(-t)=e^{-t}u(-t)$ , let me quickly check the laplace transforms of these

Comment: $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t}u(-t)e^{-st}\,dt = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-t(s+1)}\,dt  = -\dfrac{1}{s+1} = \dfrac{1}{(-s)-1}$$

Comment: It's weird we have two different properties simply by changing the limits hmm